# Netlify is not detecting GatsbyJS form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, netlify

I have made a simple contact form that takes in a name, email, and text box.

The form has all the necessary elements for Netlify to detect such as `data-netlify="true"` and `data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field"`. Everything else seems to be following the conventions explained by the Netlify/React form blogs.

`TestContactForm.component.jsx`

```js
import React, { useState } from "react"

const TestContactForm = () => {
  const [formInput, setFormInput] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    message: "",
  })

  const onChange = e => {
    setFormInput({
      ...formInput,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    })
  }

  return (
    <form
      name="contact"
      method="post"
      action="/thanks"
      data-netlify="true"
      data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field"
    >
      <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="contact" />
      <div hidden>
        <label>
          Don’t fill this out: <input name="bot-field" />
        </label>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label htmlFor="name">Hello, my name is</label>
        <input
          name="name"
          id="name"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Jane Doe"
          required
          value={formInput.name}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      </div>

      <div>
        <label htmlFor="email">Hello, my name is</label>
        <input
          name="email"
          id="email"
          type="text"
          placeholder="janedoe@work.com"
          required
          value={formInput.email}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      </div>

      <div>
        <label htmlFor="message">I want to</label>
        <textarea
          name="message"
          id="message"
          rows="5"
          maxLength="250"
          placeholder="briefly share an idea about..."
          required
          value={formInput.message}
          onChange={onChange}
        ></textarea>
      </div>

      <button type="submit">SEND</button>
    </form>
  )
}

export default TestContactForm
```

I have used practically the same code for forms on other websites hosted on Netlify, and they work fine.

`/`, `/thanks`, and `/404` are all inside the same `pages` folder within `src`.

I am not sure what went wrong with this one.

Can someone point out where the error here is spawning from?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

***Solution***

Turns out the cause of the error has nothing to do with Netlify or Gatsby.

It has to do with the animation library I was using, which was `react-spring`.

I was animating the fade in/out animation for the contact card using the `useTransition` hook, which defaults to `false` at the start. This effectively takes the contact card out of the DOM element, so Netlify was not able to detect it. As a solution, I switched to using the `useSpring` hook, which hides the contact card with `opacity: 0` and `pointer-events: none` instead.

This solved the issue.